# Neo4j/Cypher test data request

Tags: neo4j

I'm working on a project for a client and we think Neo4j and Cypher might be the right technology stack.  What I need is a test graph to try out some of the Cypher queries we'd want to run against the graph.  The test data sets on the Neo4j website are unusual in that they do not correspond to the directions they give on their video, the datasets seem to be hidden.  Does anyone have a small-ish graph (3 to 5 levels and less than 1000 nodes) that works that I could use to test out Cypher to see if it can execute the specific types of queries we will need to construct to complete our project.  The topic and contents don't matter, I just need something very simple to develop against.

thanks,

tom.

Comment: My suggestion is to create two CSV files with nodes and relationships and import them using the neo4j [batch insertion](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/batchinsert.html) utility.

Answer (score 1):

I think is best to create your own graph that correponds to your domain and then run queries against it. It is quite straightforward, you can get some inspiration by looking at http://console.neo4j.org/ where you have the cypher queries that create the graph.